# Implementing a Facebook Page Like with the Facebook Registration Plugin

Tags: facebook, seo, facebook-like, user-registration

I have read through the documentation on how to set up the Facebook Registration Plugin. In reading I saw that there are what facebook calls **named fields** and **custom fields**. What I am looking for is a check box that says "Like us on facebook". If that is clicked and the form is submitted the user auto likes our page.

I would think that there would be a field in **named fields** area that does this.

Some of the research I have done suggests that forcing an auto like on a user is black hat and could result in the deletion of your facebook page. This registration plugin seems like a good way to get the user to opt in to facebook marketing. Yes I could auto like them on submit if the box is checked but then how would facebook know that I have permission to do this.

Does anyone have a "white hat" solution to "liking" a facebook page within a form besides the obvious facebook like box plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** possible.

> Yes I could auto like them on submit

How would you do that? I can't think of a way to "Like" a Facebook Page programatically!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to like a page, you'll need to get extended permissions from the user and use the [Graph API's Publishing Feature](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing). However, this can't be done using the [Registration Social Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/).

As I said you will need to use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to **[authenticate the user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)**, while doing that you will need to [request permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) to `publish_stream` which will allow you to like your page after authentication by making a [Graph  POST request to Like the object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing).

**However**, although you *can* do this, it is far more complex than the Registration Plugin, it requires more steps and much more work on your end. However, if you ***really*** want to do it, it is certainly possibly.

Comment: So we should request that a named field be added so everything becomes seamless. Wouldn't you agree that this would be very useful?

Comment: This could be nice for you, however as I said, it can't be implemented using the registration plugin, as you can't make requests for permissions with it. Wildfire App, asks you to like them [when you sign up](https://account.wildfireapp.com/signup), this is infinitely simpler than permission requests, etc.